# How to create user command to delete current file and saveas to new file?

Tags: user-commands

I use `:saveas` to move a file while maintaining its undo history. Most of the time I immediately delete the old file. So if I'm editing `foo.txt`  I'll issue

```
:saveas bar.txt
:!rm foo.txt
```

I wanted to make this into a single command, so I'm trying

```
command! -nargs=* Move :call delete(expand('%')) | saveas arg1
```

But if I issue

```
:Move bar.txt
```

instead it creates a new file called (literally) `arg1`

I'm guessing I misunderstand how `arg1` works (and probably how `|` works).

Is there a better way to do this anyway?

Answer (score 3):

Use `<args>` when referencing command arguments. `<args>` will expand to the arguments passed to the command. Also, while not strictly required, because you **always** want to pass **one** argument to your command (the new filename) you should probably use `-nargs=1`.

I would also recommend saving the new file and **then** deleting the old file, just to be safe. You can do this by using `#` (the alternate file name) instead of `%` (the current file name) inside `expand()`. After using `:saveas`, the alternate file name is set to the the old file name.

```
command! -nargs=1 Move :saveas <args> | call delete(expand('#'))
```

---

Optionally, you could expand this to use a `!` in a way that is analogous to `:w!` (forcefully write) with the `-bang` option:

```
command! -nargs=1 -bang Move :saveas<bang> <args> | call delete(expand('#'))
```

In this case, `<bang>` will be expanded to `!` if the command was executed with `!`, otherwise it will expand to nothing.

---

Relevant help:

```
:h :saveas
:h :_#
:h :command-nargs
:h <args>
:h :command-bang
:h <bang>
```

Answer (score 3):

If plugins are an option, tpope's [eunuch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-eunuch) plugin offers `:Move` to anywhere and `:Rename` within the current directory commands, among many others.